# My function goes over the length of string

Tags: c, string, function, overflow

I am trying to make function that compares all the letters from alphabet to string I insert, and prints letters I didn't use. But when I print those letters it goes over and gives me random symbols at end. Here is link to function, how I call the function and result: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dRqRP.jpg

Here is code: (http://pastebin.com/fCyzFVAF)

```
void getAvailableLetters(char lettersGuessed[], char availableLetters[])
{
        char alphabet[]={'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z'};
        int LG,LG2,LA=0;
        for (LG=0;LG<=strlen(alphabet)-1;LG++)
        {
                for(LG2=0;LG2<=strlen(lettersGuessed)-1;LG2++)
                {
                        if (alphabet[LG]==lettersGuessed[LG2])
                        {
                                break;
                        }
                        else if(alphabet[LG]!=lettersGuessed[LG2] &&LG2==strlen(lettersGuessed)-1)
                        {
                                availableLetters[LA]=alphabet[LG];
                                LA++;
                        }
                }
        }
}
```

Here is program to call the function:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "hangman.c"

int main() 
{
    int i = 0;
    char result[30];
    char text[30];
    scanf("%s", text);

    while(i != strlen(text))
    {
        i++;
    }

    getAvailableLetters(text, result);
    printf("%s\n", result);
    printf ("%d", i);
    printf ("\n");
}
```

Here is result when I typed in abcd: efghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzUw▒ˉ

Comment: Looks like something is wrong with `getAvailableLetters`; hard to say what without seeing its implementation (relevant code should be included in the post, not linked to).  (Also: what's the point of the `while` loop?)  Finally: learn to format an comment your code!

Comment: I tried to format it properly but I failed :/ so I used pastebin. First time using this website

Comment: And yes I am aware that something is wrong in getAvailableLetters

Comment: Also dont mind the loop, it was just for test

Comment: Don't use `strlen()` in the loop conditions like you do; it gets called each time the loop iterates, which makes your algorithm explode.  Your loop in the `main()` program to determine when `i` reaches size of `strlen(text)` is bizarre; you simply write `i = strlen(text);` (with no visible loop).

Comment: I tried that with i , didnt work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`char alphabet[]={'a','b','c', ... ,'x','y','z'};` is not a string.   It is simply an "array 26 of `char`".

> In C, "A *string* is a contiguous sequence of characters terminated by and including the first null character. ...".  C11  §7.1.1 1

`strlen(alphabet)` expects a *string*.  Since code did not provide a string, the result is undefined.

To fix, insure `alphabet` is a *string*.

```
char alphabet[]={'a','b','c', ... ,'x','y','z', 0};
// or
char alphabet[]={"abc...xyz"};  // compiler appends a \0
```

Now `alphabet` is "array 27 of `char`" and also a *string*.

---

2nd issue: `for(LG2=0;LG2<=strlen(lettersGuessed)-1;LG2++)` has 2 problems.

1) Each time through the loop, code recalculates the length of the string.  Better to calculate the string length once since the string length does not change within the loop.

```
    size_t len = strlen(lettersGuessed);
    for (LG2 = 0; LG2 <= len - 1; LG2++)
```

2) `strlen()` returns the type `size_t`.  This is some unsigned integer type.  Should `lettersGuessed` have a length of 0 (it might have been `""`), the string length - 1 is not `-1`, but some very large number as unsigned arithmetic "wraps around" and the loop may never stop.  A simple solution follows.  This solution would only fail is the length of the string exceeded `INT_MAX`.

```
    int len = (int) strlen(lettersGuessed);
    for (LG2 = 0; LG2 <= len - 1; LG2++)
```

A solution without this limitation would use `size_t` throughout.

```
    size_t LG2;
    size_t len = strlen(lettersGuessed);
    for (LG2 = 0; LG2 < len; LG2++)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to print `result` as a string, you need to include a terminating null at the end of it (that's how `printf` knows when to stop).

Comment: That's a very very very basic question. Please Google printf() and basic C language tutorials.  Also you haven't shown us what your getAvailableLetters() function is doing.

Answer (score 2):

for `%s` printf stops printing when it reaches a null character `'\0'`, because `%s` expects the string to be null terminated, but `result` not null terminated and that's why you get random symbols at the end

just add `availableLetters[LA] = '\0'` at the last line in the function `getAvailableLetters`

http://pastebin.com/fCyzFVAF

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your string is NULL-terminated (e.g. has a '\0' character at the end). And that also implies ensuring the buffer that holds the string is large enough to contain the null terminator.

Sometimes one thinks they've got a null terminated string but the string has overflowed the boundary in memory and truncated away the null-terminator.  That's a reason you always want to use the form of functions (not applicable in this case) that read data, like, for example, sprintf() which should be calling snprintf() instead, and any other functions that can write into a buffer to be the form that let's you explicitly limit the length, so you don't get seriously hacked with a virus or exploit.